AWS Cognito Web Console not signing out user
I have a minimal ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC web application. I have successfully incorporated authentication and authorization into the application using AWS Cognito.
The application has an unprotected page (a page that is served by a controller not decorated with the [Authorize] attribute), a protected page (a page that is served by a controller decorated with the [Authorize] attribute), a sign in page (which redirects the user to the cognito login UI together with valid parameters) as well as a sign out page (which has one line of code which logs out the user locally by clearing local authentication cookie and a second line of code which, as I understand it, calls off to an end_session endpoint on my IDP to log out of your IDP).
I believe my projects works perfectly as intended because:

Navigating to the unprotected page is possible both when I'm signed in and signed out.
Clicking the sign in link takes me to the Cognito Sign-in page, where, if I enter a username/password combination, as signed up, I am redirected back to my web application with no errors, pursuant to which, I can access my protected web pages unhindered.
Clicking the sign in link and entering incorrect username/password gives an incorrect combination prompt from the cognito UI page
Clicking sign out has to work because pursuant to hitting this controller, I am:
a) redirected back the home page
b) if I navigate to the protected page, I am prompted to enter my credentials again
c) if I navigate to the log in link, I am prompted again to enter my credentials
If I log out, and sign back in, I'm obviously prompted a username password combination in the cognito UI and directed back if successful. If I click sign in again, immediately thereafter, I am redirected back to home (given that I'm already signed in)
To be double sure, straight after signing in, if I clear my browsers cache, I am prompted again the log in, if I either click sign in, or try to access the protected page.

I now want to know how to log out a user from the Cognito aws console.
From the AWS console, this looks easy:
User pools -> <MyUserPool> -> Actions -> Sign out user

However, clicking this doesn't seemingly do anything as I can still access protected resources on my web application.
Not only that, but disabling user access on the aws console also doesn't prevent me from accessing a protected page.
I suspect I am missing line of code/check on my protected page controller that is supposed to check whether the token the user provides has not since been invalidated from cognito.
Can anyone tell me exactly what I am missing to make it work?

you might be facing issue issue because ASP.NET Core app using AWS Cognito doesn't immediately recognize when a user is signed out or disabled in Cognito, it caches valid tokens. to resolve this issue you could try using the custom token revocation. by using this on sign-out or user disablement in Cognito, notify your application and mark the tokens as revoked in your data store, and adjust your token validation process to check this revocation status in real-time.

It is clearly mentioned "When you use the GlobalSignOut API, Amazon Cognito revokes all the access and refresh tokens that are issued to a user. Note that only Amazon Cognito is informed of the token revocation. Your application might continue to accept the tokens until they expire." at What's the difference between the logout endpoint and the GlobalSignOut API in Amazon Cognito? page. I believe, when you logout from Console, it uses the same GlobalSignOut  API under the hood.

Thank you very much, I was not aware of this fact. For the purposes of assisting others encountering the same issue, I would be happy if you post your comment as an answer where I can upvote and accept it as an answer.
